# AWS: ip-xxx.xx-xx-1.compute.internal for ip-xxx doesn't resolve to an ip address owned by this host

Tags: amazon-web-services, hostname, vpc

I have an issue in my VPC.
I try to install an ansible script. This was a success on other vpc's. But on this VPC I got the following error:

```
ip-xxx.xx-xx-1.compute.internal for ip-xxx doesn't resolve to an ip address owned by this host. 
Please set openshift_hostname variable to a hostname that when resolved on the host in question resolves to an IP address matching an interface on this host. This host will fail liveness checks for pods utilizing hostPorts, press ENTER to continue or CTRL-C to abort.:
```

It worked in other VPC's so it's an issue on my Amazon VPC. Can someone tell me which configuration is probably missing/wrong?

Comment: Is the error emerging from your ansible script? if so, what command generates it? Could you attach the ansible script and more details about the AWS instance to this question?

Comment: Yes this is turning up. But on other VPC's it worked so there is something wrong with the VPC configuration I assume. But I don't know very much about the VPC's or how they are set up. I hoped this error "doesn't resolve to an ip address owned by this host" would be known by some AWS guys.

Comment: Is the VPC identical? All route table, DNS, VPN, gateway setting EXACTLY the same with other? Launch an small EC2 instance inside the VPC and do the usual network check, e.g. ping,etc to confirm the DNS, route, security group are set properly

Comment: thanks, will do that

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem by installing OpenShift installed with ansible.
I solved it by editing the etc / hosts file because that file was the default address 127.0.0.1

I hope this tip can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem you can do the following

- Update your hostname with hostnamectl set-hostname
- Make your hostname persistent
- while running your ansible script use the variable next to each host as 
  openshift_hostname=